# Adding Container-Scanning to CI in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

So im trying to set up Container scanning in gitlab, i tried many ways but none seems to work, what im missing?

My gitlab version is: `GitLab Community Edition 12.9.4`

The gitlab-runner in the machine is: `Version: 12.10.2`

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  vulnerable_tag: vulnerable
  non_vulnerable_tag: non_vulnerable
  IMAGE_NAME: test
  CLAIR_OUTPUT: High 

stages:
    - build
    - test

build:
  image: docker
  stage: build
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: test
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  script:
    - uname -a
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 $IMAGE_NAME 
    - docker ps
    - curl localhost
    - mkdir output
    - echo $IMAGE_NAME"/"$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG":"$CI_COMMIT_SHA >> output/file.txt
  tags:
    - testingtag
#  artifacts:
#    paths: 
#      - output/

stop_container:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

Is a simple nginx container that just shows a plain index.hmtl

What i've tried (everything inside the .gitlab-ci.yml) that didnt work

```
include:
  - template: Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

This is what the documents says and how it should works, but it throws an error `` This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: Included file `Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml` is empty or does not exist! ``

```
include:
 - remote: 'https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

This throws no error, but does nothing. (the link is the same `Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml` but in plaintext)

And for last, adding the content of Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml as a job

```
# Read more about this feature here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/

variables:
  # Setting this variable will affect all Security templates
  # (SAST, Dependency Scanning, ...)
  SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers"

  CS_MAJOR_VERSION: 2

container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image: $SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX/klar:$CS_MAJOR_VERSION
  variables:
    # By default, use the latest clair vulnerabilities database, however, allow it to be overridden here with a specific image
    # to enable container scanning to run offline, or to provide a consistent list of vulnerabilities for integration testing purposes
    CLAIR_DB_IMAGE_TAG: "latest"
    CLAIR_DB_IMAGE: "$SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX/clair-vulnerabilities-db:$CLAIR_DB_IMAGE_TAG"
    # Override the GIT_STRATEGY variable in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and set it to `fetch` if you want to provide a `clair-whitelist.yml`
    # file. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/index.html#overriding-the-container-scanning-template
    # for details
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - name: $CLAIR_DB_IMAGE
      alias: clair-vulnerabilities-db
  script:
    - /analyzer run
  artifacts:
    reports:
      container_scanning: gl-container-scanning-report.json
  dependencies: []
  rules:
    - if: $CONTAINER_SCANNING_DISABLED
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH &&
          $GITLAB_FEATURES =~ /\bcontainer_scanning\b/
```

The CI just skip this job as it didnt exist

Comment: Is the issue fixed?I am getting same error

Comment: @merla no, i couldnt make it work and after a week of trying i just gave up

Answer (score 1):

GitLab community edition does not include the container scanning feature. Currently it is only available in Ultimate and Gold subscriptions as noted [at the top of this page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/).

Also this part of the CI config GitLab to skip the entire scanning step if the container scanning feature is not detected, which it won't because you are running the community edition:

```
  rules:  
    - if: $CONTAINER_SCANNING_DISABLED  
      when: never  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH &&  
          $GITLAB_FEATURES =~ /\bcontainer_scanning\b/
```

Comment: Hello. Please, next time after submitting a post check it was correctly formatted as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the path of template it includes `Security` so the following code should work:

```
include:
  - template: Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#container-scanning-available-in-all-tiers) (May 2022)

> ### Container Scanning available in all tiers
>
> [Container Scanning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/) helps developers to easily find known security vulnerabilities in dependencies that are installed in their container images.
>
> With GitLab 15.0, we are making the basic Container Scanning features available in every GitLab tier.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/#capabilities) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2233).

---

However, the following is only for Ultimate Edition with [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#operational-container-scanning) (October 2022)

> ### Operational container scanning
>
> GitLab now officially supports vulnerability scanning of container images in operational or production Kubernetes environments. You can set up scanning either through the [configuration file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/vulnerabilities.html#enable-operational-container-scanning) for your GitLab Agent for Kubernetes or by creating a [scan execution policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/policies/scan-execution-policies.html) to require scans to run on a regular cadence.
>
> Results are displayed both on the project’s **Vulnerability Report** page under the **Operational Vulnerabilities** tab and also on the **Infrastructure > Kubernetes clusters > Agent** page under the **Security** tab. To get started, make sure you have installed the [GitLab Agent for Kubernetes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/index.html) and that a scan cadence is defined either in the [agent configuration file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/vulnerabilities.html#enable-cluster-vulnerability-scanning) or in a [scan execution policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/policies/scan-execution-policies.html).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_5/secure-operational-vulnerabilities.png -- Operational container scanning]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/vulnerabilities.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3410).